# How to sort list of elements when duplicate entries exist

Tags: sorting

I'm struggling with what I thought was going to be an easy task.  Data structure is 'page' which has variable 'page_content' rows in a relational table. I am trying to allow users to update page_content.sort and set the place they want the content to reside on page.  So I need a function that takes the following scenerios and sorts the items properly.

| page_content.id | page_content.sort |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

| page_content.id | page_content.sort |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

| page_content.id | page_content.sort |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |

| page_content.id | page_content.sort |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

| page_content.id | page_content.sort |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

I tried doing this by passing in a $priority id variable that would be the definitive value that would be accepted when there are duplicates. However the function just kept getting more and more complicated and I feel like I am doing something fundamentally wrong.  I don't know a simple way to determine if, when a duplicate is found, if it should be moved up or down the list.  I hope this is clear, below is my current version of the function which fails when I try to move third table provided.  Maybe others as well.

```
    public function reindex($priority = 0)
    {
        $result = $this->content();
        if (!empty($result)){
            if (!empty($priority)){
                $count = 1;
                $cache = [];
                $append_content = 0;
                foreach ($result as $row){
                    if ($row['id'] == $priority and $row['count'] == count($result)){
                        // special handling for when priority content gets handled moved to end of list
                        $append_content = $row['id'];
                    } elseif (empty($cache[$row['sort']])){
                        $cache[$count] = $row['id'];
                        $count++;
                    } else {
                        $reindex = true;
                        if ($row['id'] == $priority){
                            // move the rest down a spot (+1) and then insert into spot assigned
                            $reindex_count = count($cache);
                            while ($reindex){
                                if ($reindex_count >= $row['sort']){
                                    $cache[$reindex_count + 1] = $cache[$reindex_count];
                                    $reindex_count--;
                                } else {
                                    $reindex = false;
                                }
                            }
                            $cache[$count] = $row['id'];
                        } else {
                            // simply insert it into the next available slot
                            // works because $result is sorted already
                            $reindex_count = $row['sort'] + 1;
                            while ($reindex){
                                if (empty($cache[$reindex_count])){
                                    $cache[$reindex_count] = $row['id'];
                                    $reindex = false;
                                } else {
                                    $reindex_count++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
                if (!empty($append_content)){
                    $cache[$count] = $append_content;
                }
                // save results
                foreach ($cache as $count => $id){
                    $this->c->db->update('page_content', ['sort' => $count], 'id = :id', [':id' => $id]);
                }
            } else {
                $count = 1;
                foreach ($result as $row){
                    $this->c->db->update('page_content', ['sort' => $count], 'id = :id', [':id' => $row['id']]);
                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }
```